# powershell multidimensional Array foreach

Tags: powershell

Powershell script (win10)

```
function eineFunction($meinHost, $meinPass){  
    Write-Host $meinHost "--"  
    Write-Host $meinPass "--"  
}  

$MeineHosts=(  
    ("host1", "pass1"),  
     ("host2", "pass2")  
   )  
  
clear  
foreach($row in $MeineHosts){  
    Write-Host $row[0]  
    Write-Host $row[1]   
    eineFunction($row[0], $row[1])  
    }
```

---

Output:

```
host1   
pass1   
host1 pass1 --  
--   
host2   
pass2  
host2 pass2 --
```

---

Output wanted:

```
host1   
pass1   
host1 --   
pass1 --   
host2   
pass2   
host2 --  
pass2 --
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Functions in PowerShell should be called *without* parens – they behave like commands. For example:

```
eineFunction $row[0] $row[1]
```

If you use `($row[0], $row[1])`, this actually creates a *new* 2-item list that'll be passed as the first parameter – and nothing as the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks.  Perfectly clear. That did the trick.

Comment: The "," has to go. Params should be "space" separated